# Does Furious Spell add damage or multiply damage?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, metamagic

I have read the description, and based on what it says, I am reading it like such:

Spell caster is level 15 → Spell is 6th level and does 1d6 every spell caster level → Spell does 15d6 → Add Furious Spell metamagic → Spell adds 2× spell level to damage of spell

Does this mean that Furious Spell

1. adds the spell's inital level, ×2, to get 12 additional damage on the 15d6? (Example: 6th level spell does 15d6; Furious spell makes it do 15d6+12.)

   *or*
2. does it mean that the damage done is essentially 2× (15d6 becomes 30d6)?

I'm assuming it's the former option because 30d6 would be stupid powerful.

Answer (score 7):

[Furious Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/furious-spell-metamagic/)

> adds twice the spell’s original level to the amount of damage dealt by the spell

In this case, twice the spell’s original level is 12, so it deals 15d6+12.

Comment: @minnmass 6 is the spell’s original level. *twice the spell’s original level* is 12.

Comment: sorry about that; missed "twice" two or three times.